# Unable to read API responce data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, python-2.x

I am trying to get data from the below seen URLs

```
import requests
import json

service_a = requests.get('https:xxxxx')

service_b = requests.get('https:xxxxx')

service_a.json()

service_b.json()
```

While for the case of service_a, service_a.json() gives me the expected data, for service_b, the call service_b.json() gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 892, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/scanner.py", line 79, in scan_once
    return _scan_once(string, idx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/scanner.py", line 70, in _scan_once
    raise JSONDecodeError(errmsg, string, idx)
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Why is this happening?

ps. I notced that when I try to visit the https link of service_a, the data it contains are shown in the browser, while for sevice_b, no data are shown in the browser, but when I click it a file with its data is downloaded in my computer.

Comment: `service_b`'s URL doesn't return json data.  It looks like CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check the Content-Type of service_b response.

```py
import csv
response = requests.get(API_URL)
decoded_data = response.content.decode("utf-8")

csv_data = csv.reader(decoded_data.splitlines(), delimiters=",")

csv_list = list(csv_data)
```

Comment: 'Content-Type': 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8'

Comment: This seems to be the content type

Comment: Ok. With this content type you can't use json().  I have edited my answer above

Answer (score 1):

in most cases your

`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`
error is due to:

- non-JSON conforming quoting
- XML/HTML output (that is, a string starting with <), or
- incompatible character encoding